# cygpath: can't convert empty path

Tags: grails, cygwin

When trying to verify the installation of grails using grails -version command in cygwin I get following message before the Grails version is displayed:

$ grails -version
**cygpath: can't convert empty path**

Grails version: 2.2.5

As per this link, http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-bug-with-cygwin-terminal-td4639236.html,
CLASSPATH needs to be set but I am not sure I understand what it means.

Created environment variables called CP and CLASSPATH but still no results.

Any suggestions or help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. Two things were changed:
- Created environment variables CP and CLASSPATH with value `cygpath --path --mixed "$CP"`
- Downloaded commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar manually into the lib folder.